# Replace an element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need to replace a value "y" with "#" in an array and also need to count the "y" value in an array.

```
x = ['a','b','c'];
z = ['z','y','y'];

var a = x.concat(z);
var b = a.sort();
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    if(b[i] == "y") {
            b['y'] == "#";
        var c = count++;
    }
}
console.log(b);
console.log(c+1);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajaovi/379wd9Lr/)

Comment: `b['y']==` should be `b[i]=`.

Comment: `b['y']` should be `b[i]` and you should use `=` instead of `==` when you are setting `b[i]`

Comment: don't forget to use `var` before declaring all new variables, btw

Comment: `=` is for assignments. use `===` for strict comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`==` is comparison operator
`=` is assignment operator**

Change to this :

```
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    if(b[i] == "y") {
```

> b[i] = "#";

```
        var c = count++;
    }
}
```

from

```
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    if(b[i] == "y") {
```

> b['y'] == "#";

```
        count++;
    }
}
```

```js
x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
z = ['z', 'y', 'y'];

var a = x.concat(z);
var b = a.sort();
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  if (b[i] == "y") {
    b[i] = "#";
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(b);
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 4):

- declare all variables
- assign the right value, do not make a comparison `b[i] = "#";`,
- use `count` variable, and not `c`
- no need to use `b`, because `sort` sorts the given array.

```js
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var z = ['z', 'y', 'y'];
var a = x.concat(z);
var count = 0;

a.sort();
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if (a[i] == "y") {
        a[i] = "#";
        count++;
    }
}
console.log(a);
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` with destructuring assignment to effectively return 2 values

```js
var x = ['a','b','c']
var z = ['z','y','y']
var a = x.concat(z)
var [count, b] = a.reduce(([count,b],x)=> {
  if (x === 'y')
    return [count + 1, [...b, '#']]
  else
    return [count, [...b, x]]
}, [0, []])

console.log(count) // 2
console.log(b)     // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'z', '#', '#']
```

---

If you really want the array sorted before replacing `'y'` and getting the count, you should know that `Array.prototype.sort` will mutate the original array. Also, assignment of an array to a variable is by reference.

So when you write this...

```
var b = a.sort();
```

You should know that `a` will be sorted, and `b` is just a second reference to the exact same array. `b` is **not** a separate copy.

If you'd like to make a separate copy, you can do this

```
// make B a sorted copy of A. do not modify A.
var b = a.slice(0).sort();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var x = ['a','b','c'];
var z = ['z','y','y'];

var a = x.concat(z);
var b = a.sort();
var count = 0;

b = b.map(function(v) {
  if(v == 'y') {
    count++;
    return '#';
  } else {
    return v;
  }
});

console.log(b);
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but is this what you want?

```js
x = ['a','b','c'];
z = ['z','y','y'];

var a = x.concat(z);
var b = a.sort();
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    if(b[i] == "y") {
      b[i] = "#";
        var c = count++;
    }
}
console.log(b);
console.log(c+1);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/icenova/379wd9Lr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are the fan of less line of code, then this one line (or maybe two line) implementation would be noticeable. ;)

---

**BUT** the main reason of my answer was about the sort return value.
as mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
>    the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order
>    is according to string Unicode code points.

So the `sort()` method do the action in place **and** returns the result (the array) too.

```js
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    z = ['z', 'y', 'y'],
    toReplace = 'y',
    replaceWith = '#',
    count = 0;

var result = x.concat(z).sort()
  .map((v, i, a) => v === toReplace ? ++count && replaceWith : v);

console.log(result, count);
```